# slurm: error: Security violation, ping RPC from uid 1000

Tags: slurm

Both my frontEnd and compute node has the same `UID` and `GID` but I am having same error on [slurm uid and gid must be consistent across the cluster](https://github.com/CSCfi/ansible-role-slurm/issues/11). How can I fix this problem?

I have builded both frontEnd and compute node as follows, could it be the reason where I also build compute node with `--enable-front-end` flag?

```
git clone https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm
cd slurm
./configure --enable-debug --enable-front-end
sudo make install
```

---

**The way I run frontEnd node:**

```
sudo killall slurmctld slurmdbd slurmd
sudo munged -f
sudo /etc/init.d/munge start

sudo slurmdbd &
sudo slurmctld -cDvvvvvv
```

**The way I run compute node:**

```
sudo killall slurmd
sudo munged -f
sudo /etc/init.d/munge start

sudo slurmd -Dvvvvv
```

*My frontEnd:*

```
$id 
uid=1000(alper) gid=1003(alper) groups=1003(alper),27(sudo),999(docker)
```

*My compute node:* (I have updated its gid it was 1001 before. I am not sure whether slurm sees its updated version or not.)

```
$id
uid=1000(alper) gid=1003(alper) groups=1003(alper),4(adm),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),1000(google-sudoers)
```

---

Log from slurmd:

```
slurmd: debug2: got this type of message 4005
slurmd: debug2: Processing RPC: REQUEST_BATCH_JOB_LAUNCH
slurmd: error: Security violation, batch launch RPC from uid 1000
slurmd: debug3: in the service_connection
slurmd: debug2: got this type of message 6011
slurmd: debug2: Processing RPC: REQUEST_TERMINATE_JOB
slurmd: debug:  _rpc_terminate_job, uid = 1000
slurmd: error: Security violation: kill_job(26) from uid 1000
slurmd: debug3: in the service_connection
slurmd: debug3: in the service_connection
slurmd: debug2: got this type of message 6011
slurmd: debug2: Processing RPC: REQUEST_TERMINATE_JOB
slurmd: debug:  _rpc_terminate_job, uid = 1000
slurmd: error: Security violation: kill_job(24) from uid 1000
slurmd: debug2: got this type of message 6011
slurmd: debug2: Processing RPC: REQUEST_TERMINATE_JOB
slurmd: debug:  _rpc_terminate_job, uid = 1000
slurmd: error: Security violation: kill_job(25) from uid 1000

slurmd: debug3: in the service_connection
slurmd: debug2: got this type of message 1008
slurmd: error: Security violation, ping RPC from uid 1000
slurmd: error: Do you have SlurmUser configured as uid 1000?
```

Log from slurmctld:

```
slurmctld: debug2: node_did_resp instance-3
slurmctld: debug2: agent maximum delay 1 seconds
slurmctld: debug2: Tree head got back 1
slurmctld: agent/is_node_resp: node:instance-3 RPC:REQUEST_TERMINATE_JOB : Invalid user id
slurmctld: debug:  node_not_resp: node instance-3 responded since msg sent
```

Comment: did you solve this? what was the problem?